# what is tpch data and how can I create it with Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, presto, trino

I am trying to get Trino/Presto work with Kafka. Both [Trino](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html) and [Presto](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/kafka-tutorial.html) tutorials talk about loading topics "with tpch data" and they give an illustration of that by using a client called kafka-tpch. There is no description of kafka-tpch on [github page](https://github.com/hgschmie/kafka-tpch) nor [maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/de.softwareforge/kafka_tpch_0811). However, the tutorial shows parameters `--prefix tpch. --tpch-type tiny`. Does anyone know what these mean?

I am using Trino's helm charts and I *think* I'm able to register Kafka as a catalog with

```
 "kafka": | 
          connector.name=kafka
          kafka.table-names=newtopic
          kafka.nodes=0.kafka.io:31120,1.kafka.io:31120
          kafka.default-schema=public
          kafka.hide-internal-columns=false
```

Consequently, I can do `SHOW tables` which gives me `[['newtopic']]`. I can also do `DESCRIBE newtopic` which gives me `[['_partition_id', 'bigint', '', 'Partition Id'], ['_partition_offset', 'bigint', '', 'Offset for the message within the partition'], ['_message_corrupt', 'boolean', '', 'Message data is corrupt'], ['_message', 'varchar', '', 'Message text'], ['_headers', 'map(varchar, array(varbinary))', '', 'Headers of the message as map'], ['_message_length', 'bigint', '', 'Total number of message bytes'], ['_key_corrupt', 'boolean', '', 'Key data is corrupt'], ['_key', 'varchar', '', 'Key text'], ['_key_length', 'bigint', '', 'Total number of key bytes'], ['_timestamp', 'timestamp(3)', '', 'Message timestamp']]`

That's as far as I get. `SELECT _message FROM newtopic LIMIT 10` gives `TrinoExternalError(type=EXTERNAL, name=KAFKA_SPLIT_ERROR, message="Cannot list splits for table 'newtopic' reading topic 'newtopic'", query_id=20220219_110406_00002_9jm62)`

My test data for `newtopic` is pretty simple and it was produced with the confluent-kafka python client and the following snippet:

```
for e in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    data = {'test-string' : e}
    p.poll(0)
    p.produce('newtopic', json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'), callback=kafka_delivery_report)
```

Answer (score 0):

[TPC-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/) is a benchmarking specification.

It's not required for using Kafka or Presto/Trino, but you can see in the source code it just produces a bunch of data https://github.com/hgschmie/kafka-tpch/blob/master/src/main/java/de/softwareforge/kafka/LoadCommand.java#L131

The `--prefix` flag shown is a string literal to place on the Kafka topic names when using the kafka-tpch utility. Like I said though, that's not required; the documentation is just showing one way to get a bunch of data into Kafka at once.

Comment: Thanks, you wouldn't happen to know what might be causing the `TrinoExternalError`? I have edited my question with the snippet I used to produce the data.

Comment: Try adding a p.flush() after your for loop

Comment: Thanks, I actually had that outside the for loop, but left it out from the snippet. The error must be caused by something else